# The sorting in the app with fragments

Tags: java, android

This phonebook application has a menu, which sorts by name or category. I do it like this in `MainActivity`:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Fragment lvFragSortBy = new ListViewFragment();

switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menuSortOrderName:
        item.setChecked(true);

        bundle.putString("sortBy", "name");

        lvFragSortBy.setArguments(bundle);
        getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragContainer, lvFragSortBy)
        .commit();
        return true;

    case R.id.menuSortOrderCategory:
        item.setChecked(true);

        bundle.putString("sortBy", "category");
        lvFragSortBy.setArguments(bundle);
        getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragContainer, lvFragSortBy)
        .commit();

        return true;
```

In `ListViewFragment`:

```
Bundle sortBundle = getArguments();
if (sortBundle != null) {
    orderBy = sortBundle.getString("sortBy");
}
```

And then:

```
protected ArrayList<Contact> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        db = new DbWorker(ctx);
        contacts = (ArrayList<Contact>) db.selectAllContacts(orderBy);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception in AsyncTask.doInBackground");
    }
    return contacts;
}
```

This code works fine but I would like to know if it can be done better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use newInstance() pattern, described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1396/fragment/4555/the-newinstance-pattern#t=201611231300428916025)

The profit of using this pattern is, developer cannot instantiate `Fragment` without providing arguments. There will be no chances that you will get default value when you try to get that value. One more thing is, whatever key is required for a fragment should be defined in `public static final String` so that no chances for string mismatch in key.